# ADLDAP Curly braces are no longer supported

Tags: php, adldap

In a old project that I am migrating I used the old adldap.
But now I have to change PHP version and old adldap doesn't work with the error:

> HP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /var/www/adLDAP/lib/adLDAP/classes/adLDAPUsers.php on line 764

The code which makes the problem is this:

```
public function encodePassword($password) {
    $password="\"".$password."\"";
    $encoded="";
    for ($i=0; $i <strlen($password); $i++) { $encoded.="{$password{$i}}\000"; }
    return $encoded;
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
for ($i=0; $i <strlen($password); $i++) { $encoded.="{$password{$i}}\000"; }
```

How can I fix it until I move to new system?

Comment: You just need to use square brackets for the array portion `{$password[$i]}`. This is where a good IDE would give you hints and be able to automatically fix things like this for you, too.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the Problem for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$encoded.="{$password{$i}}\000";
```

To:

```
$encoded.="{$password[$i]}\000";
```